# Apache Beam Python SDK: How to access timestamp of an element?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm reading messages via `ReadFromPubSub` with `timestamp_attribute=None`, which should set timestamps to the publishing time.

This way, I end up with a `PCollection` of `PubsubMessage` elements.

How can I access the timestamps of these element in order, e.g. save them to a database? The only properties I can see are `data` and `attributes`, and the `attributes` only has keys coming from Pub/Sub.

Edit:
Sample code

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    items = (p
        | ReadFromPubSub(topic=args.read_topic, with_attributes=True)
        | beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(args.time_window))
        | 'FormatMessage' >> beam.Map(format_message)
        | 'WriteRaw' >> WriteToBigQuery(args.raw_table, args.dataset,
            args.project, write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')
    )
```

where `format_message` would take a `PubsubMessage` and return a dictionary representing a row to append to the table:

```
def format_message(message):
    formatted_message = {
        'data': base64.b64encode(message.data),
        'attributes': str(message.attributes)
    }
    return formatted_message
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the python SDK, in java you would access the publish time through the [ProcessContext](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.ProcessContext.html) timestamp. If you could edit your question and show the code you are using to get the data and attributes, perhaps I can help you finding an equivalent.

Comment: Done. I tried looking for ProcessContext in python sdk, but there doesnt seem to be any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the mapped function can be modified to read additional arguments:

```
def format_message(message, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):    
    formatted_message = {
        'data': base64.b64encode(message.data),
        'attributes': str(message.attributes),
        'timestamp': float(timestamp)
    }

    return formatted_message
```

More possible parameters:
https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.7.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn

Comment: What about "messageId" added by service? It seems DoFnProcessParams does not contain it.

Comment: Not sure about that. Where is this added?

Comment: On Pub/Sub service, same as publish time.
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage

Comment: I see, possibly can be accessed in the similar manner. Maybe via `ElementParam`? Haven't looked at that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up with_attributes=True?

Hope the [Beam docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.7.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html?highlight=pubsub#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage) be helpful. The parameters include:

> with_attributes – True - output elements will be PubsubMessage
>   objects. Default to False - output elements will be of type bytes (message data
>   only).

Comment: Yes, i'm using `with_attributes=True`. But I can't find the property of the `PubsubMessage` that contains the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's (newly release?!) `timestamp_attribute` arguments when you call [beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ede5ac1a45fb52d29824d12c6a308a05b290925e/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py#L128)

but I tried on my end, it doesn't work as I had expected. Posted a new query on SO if someone wanna follow-up [DataFlow (PY 2.x SDk) ReadFromPubSub :: id_label & timestamp_attribute behaving unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036548/dataflow-py-2-x-sdk-readfrompubsub-id-label-timestamp-attribute-behaving)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know at what time this was introduced, but in addition to [shadesofdarkred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52781753/13439686) there is another way (and for example can be used in a `lambda` as well).

The [`PubsubMessage`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.38.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage) returned by [`ReadFromPubSub`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.38.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub) has an attribute `publish_time`.

Therefore, considering the code in the original question, you could easily access it using `message.publish_time`.

From the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.38.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage.publish_time):

> publish_time
>
> (datetime) Time at which the message was published. Will be reset to None if
> the Message is being written to pubsub.