# DataFlow (PY 2.x SDk) ReadFromPubSub :: id_label & timestamp_attribute behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

My apache beam pipeline (using Python SDK+ DirecrRunner for testing purpose…) is reading from Pubsub topic

The message & attributes published are as follows:

```py
message: [{"col1": "test column 1", "col2": "test column 1"}]
```

```py
attributes:{
  'event_time_v1': str(time.time()),
  'record_id': 'row-1’,
}
```

I’m using the function [beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ede5ac1a45fb52d29824d12c6a308a05b290925e/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py#L128). The code/doc mentions `id_label` and `timestamp_attribute` arguments (I believe these are very new additions?! Updated only 13 days ago..)

1. When I use `id_label` in order to assign each element a unique id for dedupe purpose, I get following error:

> NotImplementedError: DirectRunner: id_label is not supported for PubSub reads```

**why so? am I correct in my understanding that some code implementation is still missing or am I missing something here ?**

2. When I use `timestamp_attribute = 'event_time_v1’`, in order to assign my own timestamp to each element (client side event time passed in message attribute `event_time_v1`), I notice timestamp actually assigned to the element is still the message publish time

**why so? I expected it would be the time passed in `event_time_v1`**

I'm using following DoFn to print element's timestamp

`class PrintFn(beam.DoFn):`

```
      print(element, timestamp)
      return [element]
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any explanation to that

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with this today, there is actually an open issue on Jira for id_label and timestamp_attribute being unavailable in the direct runner (and I'm assuming from reading, any non dataflow runners).  I've successfully been able to use id_label when specifying DataflowRunner as the runner (with some other issues, but that's by the by).

The Jira issue is below:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4275?jql=text%20~%20%22python%20id_label%22

So, at the moment, it would appear this is not yet possible to do using the direct runner.